# PHP/C/C++ - How does your initial comment block look in your programs?

Tags: standards, coding-style, comments

I am on a large project, and have not really made any comment 'headers' in my program yet.  I just started using SVN for the project the other day.  I want to add the SVN tag $id$, but have not decided on any standard commenting.

So, my question to everyone here, is how does your initial comment block look in all your programs?

i.e:

```
/***************************************
* myProgram.c 
* revision: $id$
***************************************/
```

Comment: should be community wiki

Comment: Mine almost always has the name of the previous program I was working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use one. I don't need one.

Comment: Me neither. Although one could argue embedding SCM revision history in the header is convenient, in practice it just ends up being a giant mess that ends up being removed.

Comment: @Mike what sort of samples do you need?

Comment: Just a sample block, trying to decide what to go for.  Makis posted a sample of his.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use the same comments as the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/writingdoccomments/) ones

```
/**
 * Your comment here 
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but I don't like if they are too fancy. Something like this is enough for me:

```
/*
 * file.c
 *
 * Description:
 *
 * History:
 *
 * 
 */
```

Anything more complex is just annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Company boilerplate copyright + file author/owner and a small purpose section when relevant (eg: when the file contains a collection of small related classes with headers of their own)

Comment: How do you add author when multiple people work on the same document?

Comment: Only the main code owner is listed. Other contributors will be part of the source control history.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm coding some open-source program I usually add a BSD license, otherwise there's no standard header comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these questions:

- [Do you add information to the top of each .hpp/.cpp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318835/do-you-add-information-to-the-top-of-each-hpp-cpp-file)
- [Are comment headers and footers in your code really necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718783/are-comment-headers-and-footers-in-your-code-really-necessary)
- [Best Practice for comments in Java source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921050/best-practice-for-comments-in-java-source-files)

Answer (score 0):

Any initial comment block is a wast of space if you have a version tracking software.

Comment: A version tracking software can't guess for you what a method is doing.

Comment: @Sylvain: an initial codeblock shouldn't document a method either.

Comment: Oh yeah that's right, forgot we were talking about an initial comment block.